# The instance 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble accessing the variable user on _MenuScreenState:

```
class MenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  
  MenuScreen(this.user);
  @override
  _MenuScreenState createState() => _MenuScreenState();
}

class _MenuScreenState extends State<MenuScreen> {
  final User userInMenu = widget.user;
}
```

The problem displayed is "The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it inside `initState` like the following:

```dart
class MenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  
  MenuScreen(this.user);
  @override
  _MenuScreenState createState() => _MenuScreenState();
}

class _MenuScreenState extends State<MenuScreen> {
  User userInMenu = widget.user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userInMenu = widget.user;
  }
```

Comment: The problem in 'widget' was solved but on class 'User' i have a List and i need to copy he. When i copy these data the same problem occurs.

final List<Plant> _plants = List.from(userInMenu(here).userPlantList);
'The instance member 'userInMenu' can't be accessed in an initializer.'
obs: I have some methods to add and remove elements of the list.